# How can create a config file for reactjs apps that can changes after app builded?

Tags: reactjs, configuration

I want create a config file for my reactjs app that contains for example my base url for axios actions and i want change this file after build my app instead of change url every time then again build the app

Answer (score 0):

You  can't update static config after build, but you can make specifice build config 
For example for your axios base url

```
const BASE_URL = process.env["NODE_ENV"] == 'production' ? 'my.prod.url' : 'localhost:3000'
```

Hope it can help you !